# Oracle SQL Sort Groups

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, grouping

I have a query that returns `PartNum`, `OrderNum`, and `NeedDate`:

```
Part    Order    Date 
1       A        8/1 
2       B        6/3
2       C        1/1
3       D        7/1
3       E        6/1
```

I need to sort this to the following:

```
Part    Order    Date
2       C        1/1
2       B        6/3

3       E        6/1
3       D        7/1

1       A        8/1
```

Essentially I need them grouped by part#, and sorted by the minimum date for each part.  Is it possible to do this with one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an analytic function to associate the minimum `NeedDate` to each `PartNum` group, and then order on that:

```
SELECT PartNum, OrderNum, NeedDate
  FROM SomeTable
 ORDER BY MIN(NeedDate) OVER (PARTITION BY PartNum), PartNum
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/599eaf/1)

**EDIT:** Thank you `Bulat` for the SQLFiddle link. :)